# Are there infinite possible values of $1^i$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Are there infinite possible values of $$z=1^i$$

Since $$e^{i2k\pi}=1$$ we have

$$1^i=\left(e^{i2k\pi}\right)^i=e^{-2k\pi}$$

so for different values of $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ we get different values. Is this concept correct?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use power laws of the reals for complex values. They do not hold on that wider space. So $$\left(e^{i2k\pi}\right)^i\not=e^{-2k\pi}$$

Otherwise you can easy "proof" that $-1=1$ by $$-1 = e^{-i\pi} = \left(e^{-2i\pi}\right)^\frac{1}{2} = 1^\frac{1}{2} = 1$$

So you assume a false condition…

Comment: "You cannot use power laws of the reals for complex values. They do not hold on that wider space." This is pointing in the right direction but not precise enough: actually, one cannot **define** power laws of the reals for complex values, they do not **exist**.

Answer (score -5):

I agree with
the OP's statement that
$1^i
=\left(e^{i2k\pi}\right)^i
=e^{-2k\pi}$
for any integer $k$.
For $k=0$,
$1$ is one of the possible values.

To "check",
note that
$(1^i)^{-i}
=(1)^{i\cdot (-i)}
=1^1 = 1
$
and
$(e^{-2k\pi})^{-i}
=e^{(-2k\pi)(-i)}
=e^{2k\pi i}
=1
$.

Comment: It's very interesting then that $1^i$ has no definite value. And it's not even bounded. K tending to infinity makes it 0, k tending to negative infinity, makes it tend to infinity. Amazing.

Comment: And now we can take logarithm on your equality,  and get  $0=-2k\pi $ for all $k $. Or, to keep going with the nonsense,  we could do $$e ^{-2k\pi}=1^i=(1^{1/2})^i=1^{i/2}=(e^{2j\pi})^{i/2}=e^{-j\pi} $$ for any $k $ and any $j $, thus proving that $e=1$.